# How to setup SQLite in Kotlin?

Tags: sqlite, kotlin

I'm currently writing a chat application in Kotlin and want to implement authentication, by storing hashed passwords on my server in a database.

I don't have any experience with Databases, so I chose the most simple looking one I found after about 30 minutes of google search. SQLite.

Unfortunatly there isn't any real setup guide for SQLite in Kotlin.

Could someone please write a small step by step guide on how to :

- install SQLite
- connect to it
- use it in source code(e.g. create a table with one or two values)
- all in Kotlin if possible

I'm grateful for any help!

Comment: Are you talking about... a desktop application, a server (?? why use sqlite in a server??) or a mobile client?

Comment: I'm talking about a server.

Comment: Then you can use something more reasonable like MySQL or PostgreSQL. Then if you want to use pure-Kotlin (and not Spring Boot for example) server then you can refer to https://ryanharrison.co.uk/2018/04/14/kotlin-ktor-exposed-starter.html hopefully (Ktor is a kotlin server and Exposed is an ORM for kotlin over SQL DBs). You can also check KotlinConf 2018 for some backend-related videos and talks.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an MWE using JDBC API on Ubuntu 20.04:

```sh
sudo apt install sqlite3
SQLITE_VERSION=`sqlite3 --version | cut -d ' ' -f 1` # 3.31.1 on Ubuntu 20.04

curl -s https://get.sdkman.io | bash

sdk i java  # for JDBC
sdk i maven # for JDBC interface to SQLite (see later)
sdk i kotlin 1.4.10 # later versions are currently affected by:
# https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-43520

cat > demo.main.kts <<EOF
#!/usr/bin/env kotlin

# uses maven to install the dependency from maven central:
# reference: https://github.com/Kotlin/KEEP/blob/master/proposals/scripting-support.md#kotlin-main-kts
@file:DependsOn("org.xerial:sqlite-jdbc:$SQLITE_VERSION")

import java.sql.DriverManager
import java.sql.Connection
import java.sql.Statement
import java.sql.ResultSet

# creates or connects to database.sqlite3 file in the current directory:
var connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:database.sqlite3")

var statement = connection.createStatement()
statement.executeUpdate("drop   table if exists people")
statement.executeUpdate("create table           people (id integer, name string)")

statement.executeUpdate("insert into people values(1, 'leo')")
statement.executeUpdate("insert into people values(2, 'yui')")

var resultSet = statement.executeQuery("select * from people")
while ( resultSet.next() ) {
  println( "id = "   + resultSet.getInt("id")      )
  println( "name = " + resultSet.getString("name") )
  println()
}
connection.close()
EOF

chmod +x demo.main.kts
./demo.main.kts
```

Answer (score 0):

Sqlite doesn't work with a client-server model. The datas are stored in file of your choice, so there is no installation to do.

Maybe you can look [Exposed](https://github.com/JetBrains/Exposed). It is a kotlin library for sql database (sqlite included).
There is a documentation [here](https://github.com/JetBrains/Exposed/wiki).
You just need to add the 'org.jetbrains.exposed:exposed' depedency to gradle or maven (+ the jdbc library depedency, for SQLlite it is 'org.xerial:sqlite-jdbc').

Answer (score 0):

```
import com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpServer
import java.io.PrintWriter
import java.net.InetSocketAddress

import java.sql.* // Connection, DriverManager, SQLException
import java.util.Properties

/**
    https://www.tutorialkart.com/kotlin/connect-to-mysql-database-from-kotlin-using-jdbc/
    $ wget https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/xerial/sqlite-jdbc/3.27.2.1/sqlite-jdbc-3.27.2.1.jar
    $ kotlinc sqws.kt; kotlin -cp ".:./sqlite-jdbc-3.27.2.1.jar" SqwsKt
    Minimal embedded HTTP server in Kotlin using Java built in HttpServer
**/

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val conn = DriverManager.getConnection( "jdbc:sqlite:./sampledb.db")
    var stmt: Statement? = null
    var resultset: ResultSet? = null
    try {
        stmt = conn.createStatement()
        resultset = stmt!!.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM items;")
        if (stmt.execute("SELECT * FROM items;")) {
            resultset = stmt.resultSet
        }
    } catch (ex: SQLException) {
        // handle any errors
        ex.printStackTrace()
    }

    HttpServer.create(InetSocketAddress(8080), 0).apply {
        println("browse http://localhost:8080/hello")
        createContext("/hello") { http ->
            http.responseHeaders.add("Content-type", "text/plain")
            http.sendResponseHeaders(200, 0);
            PrintWriter(http.responseBody).use { out ->
                out.println( "ok")
                while (resultset!!.next()) {
                    out.println(resultset.getString("name"))
                }
            }
        }
        start()
    }
}
```

Please check the full documentation on [Github](https://github.com/umarudy/simple-kotlin-webserver-sqlite).

Answer (score -1):

As soon as you mention **server** then you are perhaps looking in the wrong direction. SQLite is intended as an embedded database, each device having it's unique database. Synchronisation between server and clients would have to be written and can be problematic, whilst there are many RDBMS's that cater for better for client-server solutions.

Have a look at [Appropriate Uses For SQLite](https://sqlite.org/whentouse.html).

Comment: Yes, SQLite is intended as an embedded database, each device having it's unique database. Coin has two sides. If you are looking distributes database, SQLlite can be a perfect choice, but you must build update logic yourself, meaning that it can be based on timestamps and network connection between all nodes running same database data. But if common database for all nodes is not needed, don't bother about other instances, just run your own data in your independent app of other instances.